# How do I declare and convert integers in Julia

Tags: julia

I would like to have something like the following:

```
a = UInt32(3) #scalar
a += UInt32(b) #convert by to UInt32 type
```

The only examples I can find are of declaring an array:

```
a = UInt32[3]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I could have sworn I tried this before but my example actually works.

```
b = UInt32(1)
a = UInt32(3)
a += b
```

I think I was running into problems because in JuliaPro "3" at the command line gets converted into the ternary operator.